# 14.04 Desktop Installation, Wired Connection Problems

Tags: 14.04, internet, ethernet

Okay, I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my mother's Medion Titanium MD 8030. I was trying to get the internet working on it via ethernet cable because it's situated right next to the modem; however, the ethernet isn't working while the wi-fi isn't giving me a problem (an internet USB adapter). The ethernet cable, when plugged in, tells me that there is a wired connection and I am capable of connecting to it; however, whenever I try to connect to the internet, the connection invaraibly times out. I've tried lshw -C Network and apparently Ubuntu has supplied me with a driver for the ethernet interface. Where should I begin to start diagnosing what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

change **managed=false to managed=true**.

From the top-right corner select Edit Connections, and add a new connection. Specify your ip address, netmask, gateway, and the **DNS server being 8.8.8.8**.

Then add these two lines to /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Then run:

`sudo service network-manager restart`.

Hope this helps!